# How To Change UpperCase To LowerCase

Tags: regex, notepad++

- Before:

  ```
  HOW TO ABCD EFGH
  SCRIPT SCRIPT SCRIPT
  HOW TO IJKL MNOP
  SCRIPT SCRIPT SCRIPT
  HOW TO QRST UVWX
  SCRIPT SCRIPT SCRIPT
  ```
- After:

  ```
  How To Abcd Eefgh
  Script Script Script
  How To Ijkl Mnop
  Script Script Script
  How To Qrst Uvwx
  Script Script Script
  ```

I want to keep the first `A-Z` uppercase and convert the remaining `A-Z` into lowercase.

Comment: `How` is not lowercase, nor is `QRST` nor a lot of the words in the 'After' part.

Comment: editing, please view again, help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert uppercase words (containing only `[A-Z]`), you can use the following:

Find what:

```
\b([A-Z])([A-Z]+)\b
```

Replace with:

```
$1\L$2
```

`\L` converts `$2` (the second capture group which has all but the first letter of the word) into lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Read one line and do this:

```
string text = "SCRIPT SCRIPT SCRIPT";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            text.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + ((x.Length != 1) ? string.Join("", x.Substring(1, x.Length - 1).ToLower()) : x.ToUpper()) + " "));
            string result = sb.ToString().Trim();
```

Output

Script Script Script

Answer (score 0):

The TextFX plugin for Notepad++ provides a number of case conversions. The sub menu **TextFx** => **TextFx Characters** => **Proper case** should do what you want.

Notepad++ also has some built-in case conversions via the menu **Edit** => **Convert case to**, but this does not (as of Notepad++ 6.5.2) provide the variation you want.